# Join Help Needed

Tags: postgresql, join

I have postgresql question that I think is fairly simple but I'm having trouble conceptualizing what joins I need to achieve this.

I have a table in this format:

```
Company    Agreement_num    End_of_Agreement    Contract_Amount
ABC             2               (null)              (null)
ABC           (null)          2015-01-10              10
ABC           (null)          2015-09-01              12
ACME            2               (null)              (null)
ACME          (null)          2014-06-05               5
```

I would like the table to look like this:

```
Company    Agreement_num    End_of_Agreement    Contract_Amount
ABC             2               (null)              (null)
ABC             2             2015-01-10              10
ABC             2             2015-09-01              12
ACME            2               (null)              (null)
ACME            2             2015-06-05               5
```

So basically, just insert the Agreement_num to the corresponding Company.

So that you know where I'm going, after this, I'll do a WHERE clause to grab only the rows that haven't reached their End_of_Agreement:

```
Company   Agreement_num     End_of_Agreement    Contract_Amount
ABC             2              2015-09-01             12
ACME            2              2015-06-05              5
```

Thank you!

Comment: "Corresponding" how? You did not define how to pick the number. The first part of the question seems pointless, since you only pick rows that already have an `Agreement_num` in the end - or your example data is misleading. Also missing: your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use something like:

```
SELECT
    t1.Company,
    t2.Agreement_num,
    t1.End_Of_Agreement, 
    t1.Contract_Amount
FROM
    table
    INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT company, agreement_num
            FROM table
            WHERE agreement_num IS NOT NULL
        ) t2 ON
        t1.company = t2.company
```

The subquery will fetch the agreement_num for each company and use that in the main query.

You could also use windowing functions to pull this off which makes for a smaller query:

```
SELECT
  company,
  MAX(agreement_num) OVER (PARTITION BY company) as agreement_num,
  end_of_agreement,
  contract_amount
FROM 
  table;
```

[Here's a sqlfiddle showing this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fac4/1)

Comment: Perfect. Both achieve my goal, but the windowing function is half the cost. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a JOIN, I think you need to use an aggregated function like MAX:

```
SELECT
  Company,
  MAX(Agreement_num) AS Agreement_num,
  MAX(End_of_Agreement) AS End_of_Agreement,
  MAX(Contract_Amount) AS Contract_Amount
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  Company
```

but it's not clear if Contract_Amount is always increasing. If it is not, and you want to return the Contract_Amount associated to the last End_Of_Aggreement you could use a window function in combination with DISTINCT ON:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (company)
  company,
  MAX(Agreement_num) OVER (PARTITION BY Company) AS Agreement_num,
  End_of_Agreement,
  Contract_Amount
FROM
  yourtable
ORDER BY
  company,
  end_of_agreement DESC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, the use of the aggregation function and windowing function is what I need, as opposed to a JOIN. A much more parsimonious and cheaper way of solving my problem.